# CSS rearranging divs in a square like manner

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have a div as follows in my angular2 application:

```
<div align="center">
   <div class="box {{box.color}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{'lit': box.isLit}" ng-click="boxClick(box.id)"></div>
   <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
</div>
```

This looks like following on my screen:

[image]

Corresponding CSS:

```
.box {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
}

.green {
    background-color: green;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.blue {
    background-color: blue;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.red {
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.yellow {
    background-color: yellow;
    opacity: 0.3;
}
```

I am not so good at CSS. I want to arrange these boxes in a square like manner, i.e. two boxes next to each other and other two bellow them like foursquare.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `float: left` your boxes and apply proper width to your boxes wrapper (if you need 2 boxes per line, than wrapper width is 2 * (box width) + padding + margin)

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 200px;
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: you also need to add border to that wrapper width calculation

Answer (score 2):

If you float everything left and then clear every 2n + 1 child, you should be able to stack the boxes in 2s without the need for setting any explicit pixel values:

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden; /* this is so you parent box keeps its dimensions */
}
.box {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left; /* add this to get all boxes onto the same line */
}
button {
  float: left; /* this is so button goes below and not to right of boxes */
}
button,
.box:nth-child(2n + 1) {
  clear: left;   /* add this to make 2 boxes per row and get button on it's own line */
}
.green {
  background-color: green;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.red {
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box green"></div>
  <div class="box blue"></div>
  <div class="box red"></div>
  <div class="box yellow"></div>
  <button class="button button-dark" ng-click="start()">Start</button>
</div>
```

[More information about floating and clearing](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)

Answer (score 1):

Add **ng-if** attribute in div as following, I hope this will help you.

```
<div class="box {{box.color}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{'lit': box.isLit}" ng-click="boxClick(box.id)" ng-if="$index % 2 == 0"></div>
<div class="box {{box.color}}" ng-repeat="box in boxes" ng-class="{'lit': box.isLit}" ng-click="boxClick(box.id)" ng-if="$index % 2!= 0" class="row"></div>
```

Comment: No this removed two boxes, what I want is total 4 boxes but two on above and two bellow

Comment: @Nitish   I got your problem, try with  $index % 2 != 0

Comment: This kept the other two boxes!

Comment: @Nitish    Ohh.. got it, I've changed my answer, just try once it

Comment: Yes it worked! however the answer which I accepted seems a straightforward option. Just manipulating css. Thank you so much!